# Get item selected in the custom adapter listview android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

My every list view item has its own linearlayout component.The list view is in the activity with onItemClick on itself.

In my custom adapter file, I have the onclick on this linearlayout,

```
private ArrayList<Book> bookArray; // this is the data source
 .........

LinearLayout imgLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
imgLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // fire user Like
        //*** how can I get which item is selected here?
```

But how can I get the item index whose linearlayout is clicked?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Using the `Position` in `getView(...)` method...you can able to fetch particular record.

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event check this link it will help you

Comment: @ M.D. LinearLayout imgLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout); .... is inside of the getView() alredeady.

Comment: @Mohan, it barely helps. Please read through my question first.

Comment: bookArray.get(position) will give you item index whose linearlayout is clicked

Comment: @ Dhwanik Gandhi . get the value of position is straight forward in the activity, but not in the custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) to remember positon and use it on click of LinerLayout.

in getView

```
LinearLayout imgLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
imgLayout .setTag(position);
```

and into onclick of LinerLayout take it as

```
imgLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
        //.... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag for your linear layout and inside your onClick you can get the tag which will return the position for which clickEvent get Trigger.

See below code:

```
private ArrayList<Book> bookArray; // this is the data source
 .........

LinearLayout imgLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
imgLayout.setTag(position);
imgLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // fire user Like
        //*** how can I get which item is selected here?
Log.d(TAG,"Clicked Pos of Row"+v.getTag().toString();
```